# Two Array Queue Algorithm in php

Tags: php, queue

I have two array, and want to have queueing system in third array in php

```
Array 1

3
4
5
6
7

Array 2

24 => U //Unavailable
39 => A //Available
55 => A //Available
77 => A //Available
```

Result expected:-

So in Array 3 I want the one's that are Available

```
Array 3

39 => 3
55 => 4
77 => 5
```

Also the data from Array 1 should get deleted once it is assigned to Array 3.

```
Array 1 should become

6
7
```

Let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let you know about __what__?

Comment: It is written in result expected:- @u_mulder

Comment: You know, people __do not write code__ for you here. If you need help - show some efforts. Let me know when you show efforts.

Comment: What info is needed?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have code you tried to write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with the numbers from `$array2` which are available.

```
$availables = [];
foreach ($array2 as $key => $value) {
  if ($value == 'A') $availables[] = $key;
}
```

Now we have two arrays: `$availables` and `$array1` one, and we need to combine them where one represents the keys and the other the values of the new array. You would do this with this function:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

The only thing we need to be careful about is the size of the arrays, so:

```
$size1 = count($array1);
$size2 = count($availables);
if ($size1 > $size2) $array1     = array_slice($array1,0,$size2);
if ($size2 > $size1) $availables = array_slice($availables,0,$size1);
```

and then we can combine them:

```
$array3 = array_combine($availables,$array1);
```

See: https://eval.in/1056040

It would be better to put this in a function or a method, so that changes in the arrays don't affect the original arrays.

There are, of course, lot's of other ways to do the last two steps, for instance:

```
$array3 = [];
foreach ($array1 as $key => $number)
{
  if (!isset($availables[$key])) break;
  $array3[$availables[$key]] = $number;
}
```

See: https://eval.in/1056044

Comment: how to get the last step to get array 1 please?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. However, I put it all in a function and print out all three arrays here: https://eval.in/1056125

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array[1] as $key => $value){
    if($value === 'A') $array[2][$key] = $value;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
<?php

$quee = range(1, 100);

$stations = ['1' => ['status' => 'A', 'client' => ''], '2' => ['status' => 'A', 'client' => ''], '3' => ['status' => 'U', 'client' => null], '4' => ['status' => 'A', 'client' => '']];

while ($quee) {
    foreach ($stations as $name => &$station) {
        if ($station['status'] === 'U') {
            echo 'Station ' . $name . ' is busy' . PHP_EOL;
            $station['status'] = 'A';
        } else {
            $station['status'] = 'U';
            $client = array_shift($quee);
            if ($client != null) {
                $station['client'] = $client;
                echo 'Im doing client ' . $client . ' on station ' . $name . PHP_EOL;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```